# Whats the difference between evaluating a string vs an integer in PHP?

Tags: php, string, int

I have a curious question that I ran into recently.

```
 if($somestring != "" && $somestring > 0){
  // do something.
 }
```

My questions is, are these 2 check the same thing? Doesn't a string when converted to an INT always greater than 0 in PHP? Or can a string evaluate to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off strings can be 'empty' so there is nothing in it.
Integers when nothing is set, as default set to 0

So the breakdown is

```
if ($somestring != "") // 1 - check to see if the string is not empty
if ($somestring > 0)   // 2 - Check to see of the non-empty string has a value greater than 0
```

So the author is trying to protect against loose type scripting.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for...?

https://www.php.net/types.comparisons

- `"php" == 0` is true.
- `"php" === 0` is false.

Answer (score 2):

There can be string "-1" which would be evaluated directly into -1 int

About your condition - first check if it's not empty - in that case it would be evaluted to 0. Looks like author doesn't want php to do it and require the value